# Salary calculator gives less salary when I put in more languages!

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, salary-calculator

When I include only `Swift` & `objective-c`:

[image]

When I include `Swift`, `objective-c`, `HTML`, `CSS`:

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe an averaging instead of maximizing issue? Or maybe employers dislike people who know HTML.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be the affect of having more results which lowers the average for the percentiles?

Comment: @lix You're trying to conclude how it's calculating. Eventually whatever it is it's wrong. Right? Perhaps it should take into account the language which pays the highest for a given role.

Comment: Maybe it favors people who specialize? :)

Comment: As an AI guy, this doesn't surprise me at all. Machine Learning turns up such results with high frequency, and it's a pain to explain all edge cases. Just a guess: HTML in general pays lower, so HTML writers add Swift to their resume to justify a high salary even when they just mastered Hello, World.

Comment: I guess I am, it's just the most common case that sprung to mind @Msalters you had the exact same thought path I had.

Comment: looking into it :)

Comment: @Honey "Eventually whatever it is it's wrong. Right?"  I don't think that is a given. I think it's correct for the calculator to display lower salaries when you add technologies that typically involve lower salaries. If you think it should only take into account the highest paying technology, then just leave the others off.

Comment: @meagar _then just leave the others off._ That doesn't make sense. An iOS developer who knows how to write a few webpages so they can include webpages is more valuable in our team. And it never makes sense for a more valuable team to make less money

Comment: More languages open you to more positions. If the positions it opens you to are lower paid, then of course your percentiles will go down.

Comment: @Honey If I am looking for an iOS developer, one candidate has worked on iOS all their life, and another candidate has worked on 20 different technologies, who is better?

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri I would argue that the person with exposure to more technologies has a much more diverse skill set to bring to my team, and the person who has laser focus on a single technology will have missed out on many skills. For example, it's said that learning F# makes you a better C# dev. I would agree with that.

Comment: Raging employer: "You listed HTML as a programming language! It is not! No raise for you!"

Comment: @Honey But the flip side is also true,  a web developer who knows enough Swift to update text strings isn't as valuable, market wise, as a full on Swift developer.

Comment: Rust somehow brings it up by $10k/yr for me.  And this is also in the Philly area.  (My only guess for that is that Rust knowledge correlates with more low-level C++ programmers as opposed to C++/CLI programmers.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Some technologies have a negative effect on the salary.

[As Julia said on the blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/):

> Just like last year, some technologies like PHP are associated with lower salaries for developers, and some technologies like JavaScript are used so broadly that they do not affect salary up or down.

CSS is a technology that, as PHP, is associated with lower salaries and that's what's causing the second result to be lower than the first one.

Comment: Interesting. When I added PHP and CSS together it was reduced even further to 96,000. This answer certainly explains **why** it happens. Still it seems not to be so smart.

Comment: If you're PHP+HTML+CSS+doctorate you may end up with a negative salary.

Comment: @Cœur - for good reason I'm sure

Comment: @Cœur  but it might get you an honorate History/Archaeology degree in addition to your doctorate ...

Comment: Obviously it is some naive algorithm calculating the average salary given a list of technologies. While it should be picking the highest.

Comment: Smells like a conspiracy against PHP experts who are fluent in HTML programming and do XML in their spare-time just for fun.

Comment: @Lundin maybe what it should do is sum them all together! _walks away whistling_

Comment: @Bugs Agreed, I programmed a bit Java many years ago so I should have a raise! Even though it isn't relevant for my current job. Though I also programmed VB, so maybe that will come back and haunt me... "Unfortunately, we have noted that you programmed not only VB.NET but VB6 and VBA, back in 2002. So we are cutting your salary in half."

Comment: @Lundin imagine if that was the case. "Yeah to work here you have to actually pay us". Better learn JavaScript, Python and C# rapidly to counteract.  I'm sure the Hello World will suffice as "experience".

Comment: @DavidG your salary can't be lowered just you're familiar with more technologies, that's a complete nonsense

Comment: @Zhigalin My comment isn't about whether you have a point or not. I actually agree with you, and have [already argued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373717/salary-calculator-gives-less-salary-when-i-put-in-more-languages/373725?noredirect=1#comment628525_373717) the same. I was however suggesting that saying something "looks stupid" is terrible feedback. It's incendiary, provides no context, and doesn't help in the slightest.

Comment: @Cœur and possibly [tag:early-onset-php-dementia] :D

Comment: Then however they're doing aggregation is obviously stupid and meaningless.

Comment: @Zhigalin it's not what this says though. The salary calculator looks at all positions available to you and then lists them so you can get percentile. It's not going 'based on your resume you should get X'. It's going 'based on your resume, 50 % of the jobs you have access to should offer you at least X. If I put programmer as my main skill, but then add on 'I'm an amazing burger-flipper too', there is a good chance the lowest paying job offered just became way lower, right? It's similar here. People seem to expect it to do more of an assessment of what you should expect based on your resume..

Answer (score 3):

It's the law of averages.  The system doesn't know your skill level.

If you are only a Swift developer, you are being grouped with Swift developers.

If you add HTML/CSS, you are now also being averaged in with Swift developers who know HTML/CSS (higher than Swift only) and Front End Developers who know Swift (lower than Swift only).  The later is bringing down the average salary.

If the system knew enough about you (and other candidates) to be able to differentiate the above two cases, you would see an increase.

Comment: The system does however know that your skill level doesn't likely drop just because you know more programming languages... More likely it is the contrary, especially with web programming where knowing lots of different languages is helpful.

Comment: @Lundin yes that's a good point. Hm slightly flawed

Comment: _"@Rob Osborne is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct."_ Yet Rob Osborne has 3K rep.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I think he's a new contribute to the **meta**

Comment: @Lundin I'm sure the system is just matching tags and not actually tracking your career progression.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 My rep is almost all from answering questions about Django.