# rank highest to lowest technologies in salary calculator

Tags: feature-request, salary-calculator

Given that my salary can be lowered by adding languages like PHP, CSS, etc. Reference: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373717/salary-calculator-gives-less-salary-when-i-put-in-more-languages?noredirect=1#comment628282_373717) and it can be somewhat misleading. It would be nice if the salary calculator ranked my highest paying technologies to the lowest or at least have a note mentioning that your calculated salary is reduced because of including CSS and PHP language.