# Why should I earn less if I have more qualifications?

Tags: bug, salary-calculator

Using [the salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) I can earn €75,000 in Berlin with 15 years experience as a graduate with [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_%28JavaScript_library%29) experience. When I add [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) as a qualification I can earn less: €73,000. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Similar question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373717/salary-calculator-gives-less-salary-when-i-put-in-more-languages